# Python - How to check print outputs of multiple py files?

Tags: python

I have a number of test cases in separate .py files that I want to test on a module I've created. All of these files use a py module that I've created and all these py files will print a pre-determined output (some in thousands of lines).

Is there a way to run a .py script that runs these other test .py scripts and checks the outputs? I've looked into doctest and unittests, but these relate to particular functions rather than py scripts?

EDIT: These py files print outputs rather than return values. Some of them also utilize multi-threading.

Comment: if you want to make this with multiple thread create thread for each file  then run this execfile(""test.py", variables) this will run your test scripts or you can do that with just one thread all files stored in directory ,read directory with *.py files import into list or dictinary with variables then run each of them

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import glob
lst = glob.glob("/home/test/*.py")

for each_file in lst:
   variables= {} #what ever variables to need run
   execfile(each_file, variables )
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is, you will invoke these scripts by

`subprocess.Popen(['python',file_name],universal_newlines=True,stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)`

These `stdout`,`stderr` are all file objects, they will write the result into these files. Then you can use `sleep()` for the best appropriate time you think.

And after that you can open these files and check the results.

Read more about subprocess [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).